# Django pymssql migration

Tags: python, sql-server, django, ubuntu

I have to use a MSSQL Server Database with a project made in Django, i use the **django-pymssql** dependency and all works fine at first.

When I run the initial migrations it throws me an error:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (5074, "The object 'UQ__auth_use__F3DBC5726EFED139' is dependent on column 'username'.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 16:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\nDB-Lib error message 20018, severity 16:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")

This just happend just after django migrations tries this:

> Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length...

So, i'm guessing that Django is trying to make a move on a field, but MSSQL throws the error at the time it gets altered.

I'm working on Ubuntu 16.10, so if anyone have a clue of how to avoid this error would be lot of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might check your verison of django-mssql, I believe 1.7+ isn't supposed to have this issue anymore.

Try running the following against the database:

```
alter table [user] drop constraint [UQ__auth_use__F3DBC5726EFED139];
drop index  [UQ__auth_use__F3DBC5726EFED139] on [user];
```

And rerun manage.py migrate.

[Drop Constraint Failed - unable to drop index with ALTER TABLE DROP CONSTRAINT](https://bitbucket.org/Manfre/django-mssql/issues/64/drop-constraint-failed-unable-to-drop)

Comment: Actually this is the solution. I don't know if i'm going to have more troubles going further with this setting, but i will give a try. Thanks a lot!